# Define sigma in mvncdf function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, probability, normal-distribution

So for 2 rho coefficients we have:

```
   p = mvncdf([X1, X2], [0, 0], [1 rho; rho 1])
```

But for 3 rho coefficients I am not sure how to define the sigma:
I have X1, X2, and X3, with mean zero [0, 0, 0] and rho coefficients

`rho_112, rho_113 and rho_123`

how do I define it in the function:

```
   p = mvncdf([X1, X2, X3], [0, 0, 0], [1 rho; rho 1])
```

Also very curious why we sometimes need a minus before the rho

Rho in this case is:
[image]
[How to compute lower tail probability for the Bivariate Normal Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345819/how-to-compute-lower-tail-probability-for-the-bivariate-normal-distribution/61345978#61345978)

Comment: The input to `mvncdf` is the mean and the *covariance* (usually called *sigma* or *gamma*), so what the heck is `rho` in your case?

Comment: I've added the formula for rho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aware that the density function for a multivariate normal distribution is:
[image: formula]

Hence, when [image: mu], it would be:

[image: formula]

On other hand, as [image: formula] is the correlation coefficient between [image: f] and [image: f], we can write the [covarience matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) like the following:

[image]

As [image: f] for all [image: f], we can write the covariance matrix like the following:

[image]

Therefore, for a three dimensional distribution, you can have:

```
p = mvncdf([X1, X2, X3], [0, 0, 0], [1 rho12 roh13; rho21 1 rho23; rho31 rho32 1])
```

Notice that [image: f] is not useful here. It is a correlation between three variables, but the covariance matrix just needs mutual covariances.